# How does a level 6 ranger communicate with a seagull?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-1e, animals

I'm playing as a level 6 ranger and have wild empathy and +11 in Handle Animal. I also did use the spell *speak with animals*. So isn't Handle Animal supposed to be used in this?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. Could you clarify what exactly you're trying to ask?

Comment: @V2Blast Would it be prudent to rename the question to "How does a level 6 ranger communicate with a seagull?"   May help with answers...

Comment: I just wrote  the question first came to mind but sure

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, the spell *speak with animals* does allow you to speak with animals, including a seagull. It doesn’t have any specific interaction with wild empathy or Handle Animal, but each of those can be used to make the seagull more friendly towards you and more inclined to help you.

Exactly what it takes to get a seagull’s attention and willingness to honestly answer questions is up to the DM. Your Handle Animal modifier is very high, but Handle Animal is for trained, domesticated animals—or for taming and training a wild animal. The latter, though, has to be something you’ve done with that animal since its birth; for a wild seagull you find in, ya know, the wilds, it doesn’t really apply. Wild empathy would be more appropriate in this situation, and that’s the check I would ask you to make as GM, personally.

On the other hand, my experience with seagulls is that they are curious, and more than a bit brazen—not exactly skittish animals. That may be specific to the seagulls found in areas frequented by humans, in the modern world where humans rarely—if ever—attack them, and often provide food. In the world of D&D, seagulls might be more skittish. But I suspect they would still be curious—and very, very interested in any bribes (food) you have to offer. Ultimately, I wouldn’t make it a very *difficult* wild empathy check to talk to a seagull, particularly if you were offering food.

Comment: @lostguest if you feel this answer fully covers the question asked, you can mark it as the "Accepted" answer.  You can also ask the author to clarify something specific or modify your question to get more details if you think something is missing.

Comment: sry new to this place

Comment: RE: "[M]y experience with seagulls…." But how extensive *is* that experience exactly? `:-)`

Comment: @HeyICanChan .. there are plenty of YT videos of seagulls brazenly conquering and stealing: ice crea cones, waffles or any food purchasable in / at / near the shore. So for nowadays seagulls there is ample footage to proof it

Comment: And YouTube also has at least one example of a character (albeit not a ranger and in a rather different genre to Pathfinder) trying to communicate a message to seagulls: https://youtu.be/U9t-slLl30E

Comment: @HeyICanChan I grew up within walking distance of the Atlantic ocean and can confirm that seagulls believe that they have no predators. If you feed one, he will tell all his friends and you will be harassed by a vast multitude of birds.

Comment: The important part is that the seagull's speech should be the word "food" 9 times out of 10.  "Excuse me Mr Seagull, have you seen an orc?"  "Food food not food food food not mr mrs food food food is orc food?  food"

Comment: @Yakk Are you sure it's not "mine"?